# Is the picture quality much better using HDMI versus using VGA

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, vga, external-display

I have a Samsung SMB2230H plugged into my Apple MacBook Pro using mini DisplayPort to VGA.

I am considering getting an HDMI cable and mini DisplayPort to HDMI connector and was wondering if the quality will be much better or if it's not really worthwhile?

Comment: This depends on what kind of content you're viewing. If it's a video then there won't be too much of a difference. But any text will be significantly sharper and easier to read if you use HDMI or DVI.

Comment: Yes, often noticeably better.

Comment: Can you please look at this question: 339897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I connected my PC to my TV using VGA, I swapped the cable for a DVI-> HDMI one and would not ever consider swapping back the picture was that much better. So the answer to your questions title IMHO is yes, definitely.

Reading bilic.cn's comment this probably was the biggest difference for me. The text was much crisper.

Comment: Please look at this question:  339897

Comment: What type of display does your TV use? Because if it's an LCD, there shouldn't be any difference in "cripsness" unless you're using low quality VGA cables that suffer from crosstalk. Using HDMI/DVI can't increase your contrast ratio or pixel grid resolution. How crisp your text is will ultimately depend on the underlying display hardware and the AA algorithm used in software.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté The VGA cables were the ones supplied with the monitor that was replaced. It's just a 24" LG LCD but the difference is quite noticable with HDMI

Answer (score 1):

If connecting to your TV from your PC then HDMI is 100x better but, when using computer monitors, I can't see much, if any, difference between the two.

I currently use 3 screens: 1 TV using HDMI and 2 moniters using DVI and VGA. I can't notice any difference between the monitors. 1 of them is LCD (cold-cathode backlit) and 1 of them is LCD (LED-backlit); the LED-backlit one is a lot brighter, but in quality they are the same.

Comment: Depends how big your monitor is ;-)

Comment: I must point out "led" computer monitors still use LCD technology to show you the image, the only difference from "traditional" LCD screens is they use LEDs (Light Emitting Diodes) for the backlight rather than CFLs (Compact Fluorescent Lights). There will be a slight difference in the final image, but mostly in the colour and brightness, not sharpness. The best way to test is to try the two different methods on the same monitor, and some monitors may handle VGA/DVI connections differently.

Comment: I've connected my 27" S-PVA monitor to my 2 desktops, one via DVI, the other via VGA, and honestly there really wasn't any difference IMO. With higher resolutions and longer cable lengths or lower quality cables, maybe there'd be a perceivable difference, but in the typical case, most people probably wouldn't be able to see any difference. There might be a greater difference on CRT displays though, since CRTs don't have a discrete pixel/subpixel grid like LCDs, which are equally sharp using analog and digital signals with the same resolution.